# can't edit cron.deny even using sudo?

Tags: macos, cron

I'm using a Mac OSx.  I wrote a crontab script.

The contents of the crontab are exactly this:

```
# new crontab
* * * * * /bin/echo "yep" >> /tmp/my_file.txt
```

I'm ready to run it.  So, I did the following:

```
crontab <name of file>
```

Then, I went to `/usr/lib/cron/cron.deny` to try and edit the file so that I could delete my username.

However, all I saw was `Guest` in the `cron.deny` file.  This is isn't my username, but  deleted it just in case.

But, my crontab stiil didn't run.

The man pages just say to remove your username from the `con.deny` file if you see it in there.  If my name isn't in the `crone.deny` file, what could be preventing my cronetab from running? Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It's more likely the *content* of your file that is in error - try posting that.

Comment: edited qustion appropriately, thanks @MarkSetchell.

Comment: So find the full parh to `echo` and put it in the front, e.g. `/usr/bin/echo`

Comment: Did you remember to add an extra line at the end of your crontab file?

Comment: No, I didn't.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to open the file, and I received the message:
>
> ```
> No application knows how to open /private/var/at/cron.deny
> ```

*How* did you try to open that file?

Anyway, `/usr/lib/cron/cron.deny` belongs to user `root` so you need to edit it either with:

```
$ sudo -e cron.deny
```

or in a `root` session with:

```
# vim cron.deny
```

Comment: I was able to edit it in vim, and I've updated my answer.  But my username isn't even in the cron.deny file, so I don't understand what's stopping it from running.

Comment: where in the log files and which one?  I did not see a `cron` log file in `/var/log/`.  I only saw `system.log`.